# using Google maps to draw multiple maps into page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Most of the problem ,when creating div elements using JQuery no maps get Draw in the screen,but by providing them manually the divs ,the maps are fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>

function ini(Zoom,trackPoints,elementID){
    var centerX=((trackPoints[trackPoints.length-1].lat()-trackPoints[0].lat())/2)+trackPoints[0].lat();
    var centerY=((trackPoints[trackPoints.length-1].lng()-trackPoints[0].lng())/2)+trackPoints[0].lng();
    console.log(centerX);
    console.log(centerY);
    console.log();
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(centerX,centerY)
    //var   trackCenter=Math.ceil(trackPoints.length/2)

    var mapProp = { 
      center:myCenter,
      zoom:Zoom,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP   
      };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(elementID),mapProp);  

    var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
        path:trackPoints,
        strokeColor:"#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity:0.8,
        strokeWeight:2
    });  

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: trackPoints[0],
        title:'Click to zoom'
    });         

    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: trackPoints[trackPoints.length-1],
        title:'Click to zoom'
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
    marker.setMap(map);
    marker2.setMap(map);
}



   var xPlace=new google.maps.LatLng(33.49960594357574,36.28801345825195);
    var yPlace=new google.maps.LatLng(33.50296982425457,36.26604080200195);
    //var wPlace=new google.maps.LatLng(33.51296982425457,36.22604080200195);
    var zPlace=new google.maps.LatLng(33.501180542295344,36.25514030456543);
    var centerX=zPlace.lat()-xPlace.lat();
    var centerY=zPlace.lng()-xPlace.lng();
    var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(centerX+xPlace,centerY+yPlace);
    var arr=[xPlace,yPlace,zPlace];

    function ini2(){

    In this loop I'm creating the html elements,

    for (var i = 0; i <4; i++) {
        $("#googleMap").append(function(){
            return '<div id="googleMap'+i+'"></div>';
        });
    };
```

and looping here to provide the maps into the HTML divs

```
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
ini(14,arr,"googleMap"+i);
 };
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',ini2);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:200px;"></div>
```

IF I did put the HTML divs manually the maps appears ,but dynamiclly do not

```
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `In this loop I'm creating the html elements` isn't valid javascript...

Answer (score 1):

add style="height:100%" and the maps draw. really you just need to specify a height before ini() runs, so you could probably do height="200px;" or anything else.

also simplified the .append()

```
function ini2(){
    // In this loop I'm creating the html elements,
    for (var i = 0; i <4; i++) {
        $("#googleMap").append('<div id="googleMap'+i+'" style="height:100%;"></div>');
    }

    for(var i=0;i<4;i++) {
        ini(14,arr,"googleMap"+i);
    }
}
```

here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kstarr/3jq4cw6e/)

just be sure to take note of the very last line and comment.
you'll need to restore the window-load listener, as it doesn't work on jsfiddle.